# Issue with Do While loop exiting incorrectly

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue creating this game where the aim is to join four in a row. Currently, the program just exits when it reaches the `while` condition the first time, even though according to me, it does not meet it and should do the Do While loop again. Please note the game is not finished yet.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "\t \t \t Welcome to Four In A Row" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Player 1: Please enter your name: ";
    cin >> player1name;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Player 2: Please enter your name: ";
    cin >> player2name;

    do
    {
        cout << player1name << " please enter point" << endl;
        cin >> p1x >> p1y;
        cout << endl;
        player1.setpoint(p1x, p1y); cout << endl;
        point[p1x][p1y] = 'x';
        wincheck(p1x, p1y);

        cout << player2name <<  " please enter point" << endl;
        cin >> p2x >> p2y;
        cout << endl;
        player2.setpoint2(p2x, p2y); cout << endl;
        point[p1x][p1y] = 'o';
        wincheck(p2x, p2y);

        if(wincheck != false) loopexit = 1;

    }while(loopexit == 0);

    return 0;
}

bool wincheck(int, int)
{
    int vertical = 1;
    int horizontal = 1;
    int diagonal1 = 1;
    int diagonal2 = 1;

    char player = point[p1x][p1y];
    int verticalcheck;
    int horizontalcheck;

    for(verticalcheck = p1x + 1; point[verticalcheck][p1y] == player && verticalcheck <= 5; verticalcheck++, vertical++);
    for(verticalcheck = p1y - 1; point[verticalcheck][p1y] == player && verticalcheck >= 0; verticalcheck--, vertical++);
    if(vertical >= 4) return true;

    for(horizontalcheck = p1y -1; point[p1x][horizontalcheck] == player && horizontalcheck >= 0; horizontalcheck--, horizontal++);
    for(horizontalcheck = p1y +1; point[p1x][horizontalcheck] == player && horizontalcheck <= 6; horizontalcheck++, horizontal++);
    if(horizontal>= 4) return true;

    for(verticalcheck = p1x -1, horizontalcheck = p1y -1; point[verticalcheck][horizontalcheck] == player && verticalcheck >= 0 && horizontalcheck >=0; diagonal1++, verticalcheck--, horizontalcheck--);
    for(verticalcheck = p1x +1, horizontalcheck = p1y +1; point[verticalcheck][horizontalcheck] == player && verticalcheck <= 5 && horizontalcheck <=6; diagonal1++, verticalcheck++, horizontalcheck++);
    if(diagonal1 >= 4) return true;

    for(verticalcheck = p1x -1, horizontalcheck = p1y +1; point[verticalcheck][horizontalcheck] == player && verticalcheck >= 0 && horizontalcheck <= 6; diagonal2++, verticalcheck--, horizontalcheck++);
    for(verticalcheck = p1x +1, horizontalcheck = p1y -1; point[verticalcheck][horizontalcheck] == player && verticalcheck <= 5 && horizontalcheck >=0 ; diagonal2++, verticalcheck++, horizontalcheck--);

    if(diagonal2 >= 4) return true;
    else return false;
```

Comment: What is the variable loopexit's initial value? Your while condition checks if loopexit equals zero, but you don't set it to zero anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: It has been set to 0 outside the main. Thought the rest of the code would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are at least three errors in this program:

1. `point[p1x][p1y] = 'o';` should probably use `p2x` and `p2y` instead
2. The check should be `if (wincheck(p1x, p1y)) loopexit = 1;` and the same for checking `p2x`/`p2y` move
3. If move of player 1 ended the game you don't want to ask for the move of player 2.

The program as it is now is behaving strangely because you're calling the `wincheck` function but are ignoring the result. Later your test

```
if (wincheck != false)
```

is not calling the function, but just reasoning about the function address and for some strange C++ rules it can unfortunately be compared to `false` (the technical reason is that `false` is a constant integral expression of value 0 and therefore can be intended to be the null pointer; why C++ has such a convoluted and strange rule for the null pointer is a secret no one really knows).